# Match a specific number of occurences of a string

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to check a page source to basically check the number of occurrences of the word 'http' hasn't changed as a basic way of confirming that the page source hasn't been modified.

for example I'd like to test the following source and match the fact that http has come up 4 times

```
<html>the following page http://example.com/a 

describes links that can also be found 
here, <a href="http://example.com/a"> here: http://example.com/a </a> and http://example.com/a 
</html>
```

What's an example regex that would match the four occurrences of http?

Comment: You want to get the count of duplicate link? Could you please be specific &  update your question with more details?

Comment: perl -e 'undef $/;$content=<ARGV>;$count=0;while($content=~/http/g){$count++;}print "$count\n";' test

Comment: `perl -00 -nE '@x = $_=~ /\bhtml\b/ig;say scalar@x;' file.txt`

Comment: @AbhiNickz I made a typo at the beginning I should have written 'http'. The answer below was what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to group your search and use it 4 times.
E.g.

```
/(http.*){4}/s
```

matches if the term http is included at least 4 times.

The s modifier at the end would ensure that .* also matches newlines

Comment: Many thanks that's exactly what I wanted couldn't find it anywhere,. Will run some tests and accept in a while.